# Temporary failurew resolving 'http.kali.org'

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux, filezilla

E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/g/gcc-10/gcc-10-base324-1_amd64.deb
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I am trying to install FileZilla on Kali and I continue to get this error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Did you touched your `/etc/apt/sources.list` ? Cause there a comma `,` in the URL that shouldn't be here.
2. As suggested by error message, and once you fixed the comma on the URL, just try running `apt-get update`

Comment: It seems that the package is not there though

Comment: @guillermochamorro that's why i suggested running  `apt-get update`. There's other versions under the directory see: http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/g/gcc-10/ the most recent one looks to be http://http.kali.org/kali/pool/main/g/gcc-10/gcc-10-base_10-20200324-1_arm64.deb

Comment: Don't mind the comma...typo